# How to convert a range list into their own separate list with different names?

Tags: python

I am making a program to estimate tile jobs easier. I have the user input the number of different tiles there are into a range list (ex: `Tile = [1,2,3,4,5]`)

Now I would like to convert every one of those numbers into their own list (ex: 1 becomes TileA, 2 becomes TileB, etc).

```
nbtile = input("How many different types of tile is there?")

tile = list(range(1,(int(nbtile)+1)))
```

Comment: You don't want to do that, really, as it'll make the rest of your code *much harder to write*.

Comment: Must the new lists have names like TileA, TileB... or do you just want a number of new lists according to the number of elements in Tile?

Comment: I would like it to have a name like that because in my code I have rooms, tile and cement, all in multiple. My goal in here is to associate a numercal value to my new item ex: TileA=24

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple generator expression:

```
nbtile = input("How many different types of tile is there?")

tile = list(range(1,(int(nbtile)+1)))

tiles, tiledict = [[x] for x in tile], {}

for x in range(len(tiles)):
    tiledict[f'TILE{x+1}'] = tiles[x]

print(tiledict)
```

Comment: mmm might work, I have no idea. I am a beginner, and I don't understand anything you wrote after my code, sorry, thanks for trying.

Comment: the generator creates a list containing each number in `tile`. the `for loop` stores each element of `tiles` in a `dictionary` named `tiledict`

Comment: ahhhhhh I think I get it. Thanks! Ill give it a try. Thanks for being patient

Comment: you my sir, are the man. works perfect!